# iOS - Storyboard Error occur app crash during app launching

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

My app keeps getting rejected because of Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

I got a crash report from judge.

I think my storyboard make some issue for this.

but I can't solve this problen a few week..

Only thing that I can guess is BaseCollectionViewCell in line 39

But that file doesn't have any special role.

It just print log when deinit.

Let me know any idea about below problem if you know.

Thanks

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x195659e88 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x18ea078d8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   UIKitCore                              0x197c1d16c -[UIStoryboard initWithBundle:storyboardFileName:identifierToNibNameMap:identifierToExternalStoryboardReferenceMap:designatedEntryPointIdentifier:designatedMenuIdentifier:] + 0
3   UIKitCore                              0x197ab3590 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 80
4   UIKitCore                              0x197beef24 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 156
5   UIKitCore                              0x197b65ee0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 688
6   UIKitCore                              0x197b65bd4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 132
7   UIKitCore                              0x1978ab600 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 108
8   UIKitCore                              0x197bed918 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216
9   UIKitCore                              0x197a9dfa4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 220
10  UIKitCore                              0x197a9ddcc -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 620
11  UIKitCore                              0x197a9d97c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 252
12  UIKitCore                              0x197a9d848 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148
13  UIKitCore                              0x19817ffa8 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736
14  UIKitCore                              0x198218f98 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224
15  UIKitCore                              0x197949958 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316
16  UIKitCore                              0x197dbc7a8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.214 + 556
17  UIKitCore                              0x197a1c0b8 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216
18  UIKitCore                              0x197a1bf28 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244
19  UIKitCore                              0x197a1b47c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 520
20  UIKitCore                              0x197a1b208 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288
21  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ab269500 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 344
22  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ab2a851c __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.78 + 120
23  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ab26d294 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
24  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ab2a8154 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 360
25  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19cc25fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
26  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19cc29a5c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
27  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ab2773b0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ab276f4c -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
29  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ab27972c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
30  CoreFoundation                         0x195725f54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
31  CoreFoundation                         0x19573232c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
32  CoreFoundation                         0x1956b6210 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
33  CoreFoundation                         0x1956cbba8 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
34  CoreFoundation                         0x1956d0ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
35  GraphicsServices                       0x1ce12d368 GSEventRunModal + 164
36  UIKitCore                              0x197baf3d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
37  UIKitCore                              0x197baf034 UIApplicationMain + 340
38  libswiftUIKit.dylib                    0x19e19b308 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 104
39  MyApp                                  0x102aab394 main + 29588 (BaseCollectionViewCell.swift:0)
40  dyld                                   0x1b3d28960 start + 2528
```

Comment: Did you test your app on your own iOS device? Make sure you delete the app from the device then do a clean build.

Comment: Yes. this crash_report got from appstore review.
I rejected my app new version.
When I test with my own device and even clean build I didn't face this problem.
@HangarRash

Answer (score -1):

This kind of crash occurs on some devices when you don't update UI on main thread.

Check `BaseCollectionViewCell` and for all UI operations use main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    Update UI here
}
```

Don't forget to read:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-the-cause-of-common-crashes

Comment: The crash log posted in the question shows it is on thread 0 - that's the main thread.